# C++ abstract class with nested class

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

I want to design a base class with some nested structure:

```
class base {
public:
  struct PtrType;
  virtual bool free(const PtrType& ptr) = 0;
};
```

for forcing all the derived class to implement their own `PtrType`, like:

```
class derived : public base {
 public:
   struct PtrType {
     int a;
   };
   bool free(const PtrType& ptr) override { return true; }
};
```

But this implementation encounters two problems:

1. the compiler allow the derived class nested `PtrType`'s `free` unimplemented, if I write the base as

```
class base {
public:
 struct PtrType{
   virtual bool free() = 0;
 };
 virtual bool free(const PtrType& ptr) = 0;
};
```

2. the `override` keyword is not allowed.

My question is, how should I implement this base class to force all the derived class to implement some certain nested classes?

Comment: Why do you want to force all subclasses to implement it as a subclass? My solution would be to make base a templated class, where ptrtype is the template parameter.

Comment: @gerum these derived class will be used as template parameter for other class template, and this class template requires some nested classes/structures as some methods return type or parameter type. using template will make other implementation too complex.

Comment: `base::Ptrtype` and `derived::PtrType` are unrelated, they just have same name (but in different scope).

Comment: CRTP might be a way to enforce some interfaces.

Comment: "... will make other implementation too complex." I believe you are on the wrong track. If some template expects a `T::PtrType` then it is that template that should check the existance. I think your current approach is making things "too complex". If the template is relying on `T::PtrType` to exists then you already get a compiler error when instantiating the template. In that sense, subclasses are already forced to provide the type

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand *why* you want this, but to solve the `override` problem you need to make `derived::PtrType` inherit from `base::PtrType` since they are currently two unrelated classes.

Example:

```cpp
class base {
public:
    struct PtrType{};
    virtual bool free(const PtrType& ptr) = 0;
};

class derived : public base {
public:
    struct PtrType : base::PtrType {
        int a;
    };
    bool free(const base::PtrType& ptr) override { return true; }
};
```

Note that the name of `derived::PtrType` doesn't matter here. You could make it:

```
class derived : public base {
public:
    struct Foo : base::PtrType {
        int a;
    };
    bool free(const base::PtrType& ptr) override { return true; }
};
```

Comment: I want to force all the derived classes to maintain a similar structure as the base.

Comment: but I find that inheritance works well with the pure virtual methods, but not the nested structure/class.

Comment: @Patrick You need to specify exactly what properties you need the derived classes to have. It's possible to catch some wrongdoings with type traits. If it's not possible to catch it - why enforce it? If you need to have knowledge about the derived class _in_ the base class, perhaps CRTP would be an option?

Comment: @Patrick And in my answer you get both pure virtual and nested classes so it should solve the problem as described.